# Changes to scala not appearing in jar

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jar, terasort

I'm using [ehiggs terasort](https://github.com/ehiggs/spark-terasort).

The project is comprised of Java and Scala. I want to edit some of the Scala. Initially I'm only adding a `println` to com.github.ehiggs.spark.terasort.TeraGen.scala.

I made the change and saved the file.

I then ran `mvn install` as per the README. When I use the jar that gets created the additional `println` I added doesn't appear.

I also tried running variations of `mvn clean install`, `mvn clean build`, `mvn clean package` but had no luck. I even deleted the jar files to ensure that new ones would be generated.

Does anybody know why this might be?

**EDIT**
The `println` I added was to file [TeraGen.scala](https://github.com/ehiggs/spark-terasort/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/ehiggs/spark/terasort/TeraGen.scala).

In the section:

```
println("===========================================================================")
println("===========================================================================")
println(s"Input size: $size")
println(s"Total number of records: $numRecords")
println(s"Number of output partitions: $parts")
println("Number of records/output partition: " + (numRecords / parts))
println("===========================================================================")
println("===========================================================================")
```

I changed to:

```
println("===========================================================================")
println("===========================================================================")
println("===========================================================================")
println(s"Input size: $size")
println(s"Total number of records: $numRecords")
println(s"Number of output partitions: $parts")
println("Number of records/output partition: " + (numRecords / parts))
println("===========================================================================")
println("===========================================================================")
```

The third `println` never appears though.

**Update**
I tested the jar on a different server and it works as expected but it still doesn't work on my local machine. Is it possible that Spark is caching the job in some way?

Just as an extra piece of info. If I edit the scala file on my Mac and build the jar and run it on my local machine the change doesn't appear. If I then scp the jar to a remote server and run it the change appears. From this I feel certain the change is included in the jar but something is stopping it from appearing when I run on my local machine.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the code where you added the `println`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got to the bottom of this.

The new jar that I was tryig to run(which contained my changes) was getting run from one location. I noticed there was an earlier veraion of the jar in my spark/jars folder so I deleted it and restarted Spark. The new jar was then picked up.

FYI, I only noticed this when I deleted my new jar and ran the script again. Even though I got an error stating the jar could not be found, I could see from the jab log that some version of the jar was executing so I did a search on the hard drive for the jar name.